# How to add tomcat server on visual studio code?

Tags: java, macos, spring-boot

My current spring boot project is running without error, but it cannot show on the Web page. I think because I need a Tomcat server.
So I installed it from extension called `Tomcat for Java`

But after I installed it, I can't find its location path. So I cant add a tomcat server and cant run on the web page. In the window computer, it is can select easily.

I am using mac . Please guide me with it

[image]

Comment: Spring boot apps use embedded tomcat server to run. They run as a standalone java applications. Read more about it [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#getting-started-introducing-spring-boot).

Comment: What error are you getting when trying to access it from browser? and what url you are trying to access?

Comment: @AnilBhaskar I think when spring boot is running , it can't also produce server port . See the above picture. Normally Spring console shows on which port being run.

Comment: It generally runs on 8080 by default, if you have not given any other port in your `application.properties`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you don't need another tomcat to run your spring boot application as spring boot has a tomcat embedded for you by default (Provided you have [`spring-boot-starter-web`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-web) dependency in your `pom.xml` file).

Once you have coded everything, go to your project directory and do a

```bash
mvn clean install
```

This will package your application into a jar/war file (based on `pom.xml`). In your **target** folder you will have a jar/war file generated. You can simply open terminal in your **target** folder and run

```bash
java -jar your_JarName.jar
```

This will start your spring boot app. Now go to the browser and load `http://localhost:8080/hello?name=abc` you should be able to see the output.

If it doesn't work, check if you have changed the default port in your `application.properties` file. If your `application.properties` has `server.port=8081` then you need to modify your URL accordingly `http://localhost:8081/hello?name=abc`

Comment: Thank ! look like I miss starter-web dependency .